# Send sms using core telophony?

Tags: ios4, sms, jailbreak

I want to develop an application like biteSMS (for jailbroken iPhone). I have tried to compile an open source application [iPhone-Delivery-Report](http://code.google.com/p/iphone-delivery-report/) but unable to compile it. Does some one knows anything related to core-telephony sms sending for jailbroken iPhone? A sample code would be very helpful.

**UPDATE**

Thanks to joshua Son for the great help.

Here is the screenshot of the warnings.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this code;

```
[[CTMessageCenter sharedMessageCenter] sendSMSWithText:@"Your Message here" 
                                  serviceCenter:nil 
                                      toAddress:@"Receiver's Phone Number here"];
```

Comment: I know this code but it gives error : 'CTMessageCenter' undeclared (first use in this function)

Comment: U must import proper headers.   Wait up I will look for mine

Comment: You ned to add CoreTelephony headers. Did you do that?

Comment: and where I can get that headers? I have added this line on top #import <CoreTelephony/CTMessageCenter.h>
but it shows errors

Comment: give me ur email address, I will zip them and sent them to ur email address. i tried to attach in this article, but i cannot find how to.

Comment: Here is my mail address rahul.vyas.09@gmail.com thanks for help. Can you tell me how to use iPhone tool chain or is it not necessary because I have official developer account? I want something like bitesms. Please send details in email like where to put those headers files and I know a little bit about jailbroken. I know how to ftp in jailbroken. So either give me a simple demo to send and receieve sms and how to install that demo. Thank you so much for your help. I'm looking for this from last 3 months.

Comment: I have sent you a guide line of sending and receiving sms messages. By the way, you don't need to jailbreak your phone to send and receive sms messages. Mine is not. To make an app like bitesms, surely you need to jailbreak, coz bitesms reads data from SMS.db which is not the database that ordinary app can reach out. For iPhone tool chain, I have no idea. I never worried about that. Though I have an official developer account. Hope you understood my english, since I am Korean.~

Comment: Actually I want to send sms using my owen app and I don't want to use MFMessageComposer. I want biteSMS like functionality in my app. Can you guide me in this direction?

Comment: Will the core telepony work in normal device ? Apple will reject the app if we use private frameworks. Isn't it?

Comment: I almost finished my app to send and receive sms. By the way, I am stuck with encoding. When I send pure 7-bit data(which is almost english), there ain't problem. But with Chinese Simplified Characters, there are some problems with encoding. If you face that problem soon or later, let's figure out together. Thx in advance.

Comment: I'm 90% sure that apple will reject your and my app coz we used apple's private api. Even it's not the reason, Apple wouldn't let us to send SMS without their public guide line which is MFMessageComposer. CoreTelephony works perfect for your desire. and it works in normal device. As I said biteSMS also listen for callback from coretelephony but it reads data from SMS.db since they don't have those data in their own db(biteSMS.db). I've looked it up.

Comment: Can you please send me a demo app which just send and receive SMS. In my company java devs have developed sms app I need to develop app same as java.I have send you a mail please check. Thanks for quick reply.

Comment: I am getting this warning: implicit declaration of function 'CTTelephonyCenterAddObserver' also lot of warnings

Comment: I have added a screenshot to question.

Comment: I will need a few days to make a demo app coz i am away from computer by wednesday. Will send u by email.

Comment: I have a good news for you. I have asked my elder cousin brother about your problem and he said that he can solve that issue you are getting for chinese simplified. He asked me to ask you what problem you are getting.

Comment: Also tell me how to disable os notification from being displayed? like biteSMS is doing.

Comment: @JoshuaSon hi can u send me CoreTelephony/CTMessageCenter files.

Comment: How to import the  CoreTelephony/CTMessageCenter header files

Comment: @Anupama You will have to find it by yourself from the internet. They are CDStructures.h, CKService.h, CKSMSMessageDelivery.h, CKSMSService.h, CTMessage.h, CTMessageCenter.h, CTMessagePart.h, CTPhoneNumber.h. If you need them, let me know your email address then I can send you mine.

Comment: I imported from GitHub but it gives error like NSObject file is not found

Comment: @Anupama Are you working on iOS Objective-C? NSObject is very basic object in objective-c. You cannot have that kind of error. As long as I cannot see your code, I am so helpless.

Comment: yes.please send me the files to this adress anupama.kk@infomazeapps.com

Comment: @Joshua Son I am using iOS 7 but message is not delivered to Entered number.pls tell me the reason

Answer (score 2):

I'm not saying the `CTMessageCenter` implementation doesn't work, but this is another option, [taken from the code found here](https://github.com/treason/WifiSMS/blob/master/wifiSMS/Classes/MyHTTPConnection.m):

```
        CKSMSService *smsService = [CKSMSService sharedSMSService];

        //id ct = CTTelephonyCenterGetDefault();
        CKConversationList *conversationList = nil;

        NSString *value =[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion];          
        if([value hasPrefix:@"5"])
        {
            //CKMadridService *madridService = [CKMadridService sharedMadridService];
            //NSString *foo = [madridService _temporaryFileURLforGUID:@"A5F70DCD-F145-4D02-B308-B7EA6C248BB2"];

            NSLog(@"Sending SMS");
            conversationList = [CKConversationList sharedConversationList];
            CKSMSEntity *ckEntity = [smsService copyEntityForAddressString:Phone];
            CKConversation *conversation = [conversationList conversationForRecipients:[NSArray arrayWithObject:ckEntity] create:TRUE service:smsService];
            NSString *groupID = [conversation groupID];           
            CKSMSMessage *ckMsg = [smsService _newSMSMessageWithText:msg forConversation:conversation];
            [smsService sendMessage:ckMsg];
            [ckMsg release];     

        } else {
            //4.0
            id ct = CTTelephonyCenterGetDefault();
            void* address = CKSMSAddressCreateWithString(pid); 

            int group = [grp intValue];         

            if (group <= 0) {
                group = CKSMSRecordCreateGroupWithMembers([NSArray arrayWithObject:address]);       
            }

            void *msg_to_send = _CKSMSRecordCreateWithGroupAndAssociation(NULL, address, msg, group, 0);    
            CKSMSRecordSend(ct, msg_to_send);        
        }
```

In order to use the `CKSMSService` class, link against the **private** ChatKit.framework in your project, and `#import` the [CKSMSService.h header](http://developer.limneos.net/index.php?framework=ChatKit.framework&header=CKSMSService.h).  The compiler might tell you that you need some other headers from ChatKit, which you can find in the same place (as my link).  Just copy those header files into the source directory for your application and

```
#import "CKSMSService.h"
```

before using them.