# Send SMS programmatically, without the SMS composer window

Tags: iphone, interface, sms

Until yesterday I thought that it was not possible to send background SMS without using the IOS SMS interface (Which many people here assure also). However, today I downloaded a new app called SmartSender, which schedules your SMS and then sends it automatically.

I tested it and the SMS is not actually sent on background, but a local notification appears and when you click on it to bring app to foreground, the SMS is sent automatically.

How could this be achieved?

Maybe Apple approved the app because the interface is very clear on what you are doing and what you are sending, but how can you send SMS without showing the interface?

---

Update: The scheduled SMS appear on my phone Messages app as sent, so I don't think that they are using another service to send SMS, also the receiver phone is indicated that the SMS was sent from my phone.

---

Update 2: OK I'm using and watching the app doing this, so IT IS POSSIBLE without showing the default interface, I'm not asking whether this can be done or not. I am using it with all internet connections turned OFF, and the message is sent from MY PHONE so it appears on the MESSAGES APP. So the app is not using any third party service.

---

Update 3: I will accept my own answer, in fact it is not possible; however it was when the question was answered. The App in question has now specified in its description that it won't work in iOS 6, so I think Apple patched some bug that could be exploited to achieve this functionality.

Comment: Aren't they using their own SMS gateway?

Comment: They must be using their own SMS gateway to achieve this, and once the sms is sent, they send a notification to the user. But there is no way around. Unless you're not planning to distribute your app through app store.

Comment: @RaphaelAyres, read my edit please

Comment: @htafoya: Please refer to my answer. It will surely help you.

Comment: Which SDK version you're using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In fact it is not possible; however it was when the question was answered.

The App in question has now specified in its description that it won't work under IOS 6, so I think apple patched some bug that could be exploited to achieve this functionality.

Answer (score 7):

Having tried the app, I can verify that it **does** send SMS programmatically, without showing the SMS interface. And it clearly doesn't happen through a third-party service, since the message gets sent as an iMessage when possible.

It's also clear from all the other answers that there aren't any public APIs for sending SMS programmatically, so the developer must have used a private API and yet somehow snuck this app through the approval process.

Specifically, it seems he used the CoreTelephony API. [This post on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6920721/689356) describes the procedure. Apparently you'll also need to get your hands on the CoreTelephony header files somewhere.

Comment: -1 for your random -1 on this thread and because `CTMessageCenter sendSMSWithText` is a **private API**. _If you read others responses, you can observe that ALL of users speak about third part or undocumented api or web based sms and you respond with an undocumented method??_ There is no documentation about CTMessageCenter: http://goo.gl/GWp85

Comment: The OP wants to know how SmartSender programmatically sends SMS. If you actually tried the app, you'd know it does send SMS programmatically. None of the other answers accomplish that, and that's why I downvoted them. My citing a private API is irrelevant. The OP wants to know how to programmatically send SMS, and there's no other way. I'm sorry you felt a need to downvote my answer just because you're upset, but that's not [what downvotes are for](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/vote-down). In the future, I hope you can be more mature and cast votes based on merit, not personal feelings.

Answer (score 5):

I've been looking into the SMS send/receive limitation on iOS for a few days, using iOS 6 and XCode 4.5 (latest as of writing). I was curious about this SmartSender application so I purchased it.

I don't know if it's because I only tried it on iOS 6, but I get the standard message controller (MFMessageComposeViewController) to send messages. I have tried delayed send - I get the message controller at prescribed time and have to manually click on Send. I have tried immediate send - that pops up the controller and I also have to manually click on Send. If I click on Cancel, the app actually loops me back into the message controller (I can't cancel unless I kill the app!)

So true, this allows entering messages from a custom UI, but then the message itself is copied into the MFMessageComposeViewController and that is what sends the SMS. So App Store approved, but nothing like what we're all looking for!

Comment: Ok, thanks for your comments. Maybe it was a bug on IOS 5 and now it's fixed on IOS 6.

Answer (score 4):

You can not send SMS programmatically in background, you can use following third party API to send the text message (SMS).

1. http://www.twilio.com/
2. http://www.nexmo.com/
3. https://www.tropo.com/

I would suggest [nexmo](http://www.nexmo.com/), its easy to use and support international messages also.

Comment: The app is not using any third party service, it works without internet connection and messages are sent from my phone as they appear on the messages app

Comment: -1: I tried the app the OP mentioned, and it **does** send SMS in the background.

Comment: @WildFire I am trying with twilio implementations to send SMS in background, so will it be approved by apple when I send it for review? any ideas?

Comment: @Manish it's look like we can send SMS from backend but is it possible to send SMS directly from client(ios app)? i am not able to find any doc regarding it..

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: @"sms:+3912345678"];
```

it doesn't work on simulator... and you cannot send programmatically sms!

Tested on iOS < 6.

Comment: This does not work anymore. Apple removed support to this to avoid sms spamming and unwanted sms sending.

Comment: -1: I tried the app the OP mentioned, and it **does** send SMS in the background.

Comment: sms application is not available in simulator and there is no application handling this url, so it doesn't work in simulator.. but it will work fine in device where there is a message app available for handling this url (This wouldn't work in ios-6 as mentioned above)

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to send SMS programmatically. You may want to investigate a 3rd party service service for sending SMS like Twilio.

Comment: thanks but I'm using the application and watching it work without internet connection, and without showing the default interface.

Comment: -1: I tried the app the OP mentioned, and it **does** send SMS in the background. It even gets sent as an iMessage where applicable, so it is clearly happening on the device, not on a third-party service.