# Send text message without show message composer or in bckground in iphone

Tags: iphone, background-process, sendmessage

Hi is it possible to send text message in background..?My new requirement is to send SMS if there is no internet connection . 
I am trying MFMessageViewComposer but it shows the pop up view.

How can we send message without shown this pop up? Is there any other way to do this things.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Send SMS programmatically, without the SMS composer window](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9570642/send-sms-programmatically-without-the-sms-composer-window)

Answer (score 0):

It's not allowed. For example, what if I develop an app which send taxed SMS to a server of mine to get money ? That´s the main reason... I could also send innaproriate or SPAM SMS to random numbers...
That's why the user has to validate the sending.

Answer (score 0):

[Send SMS programmatically, without the SMS composer window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9570642/iphone-sdk-send-sms-programmatically-without-the-sms-composer-window) hope that helps... Looks to be a similar question. According to the poster, ios6 does not allow you to send SMS in the background, without using a 3rd party API, like [Nexmo](http://www.nexmo.com/), who provide a REST API to send messages using HTTP.

To send a message using Nexmo, just send a request like http://rest.nexmo.com/sms/json?api_key=n3xm0rocks&api_secret=12ab34cd&from=MyCompany20&to=447525856424&text=hello+hd1 and you'll get back JSON, change the endpoint to xml if you prefer that.