# Send background SMS programmatically in ios 8

Tags: objective-c, ios8, sms, theos

I don't want ask duplicate question but i can't find my answer with searching.

I want send background SMS without using the iOS SMS interface. i see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9570642/send-sms-programmatically-without-the-sms-composer-window) question and i read answers and descriptions but it was for ios 6 and asked in 3 years ago and it wasn't useful for me.

Now, how can i send sms in background for iOS 8 with objective C language?

Actually, i know that we can send sms in background with swift in ios 8 and i have tested it. but now i use objective C in THEOS project with jail-broken iphone6.

Can you help me?

Comment: I recommend learning more about reverse engineering and finding out how Apple sends the SMS itself. Then, call these methods through your THEOS hook. If you've done it in Swift, just translate it to ObjC, but I don't believe that you got this working in Swift.

Comment: Could you give the reference for Swift on how to send background SMS. Thanks.